# Web Farm + XML file for data storage

Tags: asp.net, xml

We have a web farm with two web servers. We are using XML file (stored inside web application) for data storage and convert this XML file to Excel and then email the file once a new record is added to the XML file. We didn't realize that since we were on web farm we will be having two different XML files, one for each server. Moreover, these files will have different data. 
 Any suggestions how we can handle this situation.?

Answer (score 1):

Ideas

1. Use a centralized database server to store XML file.
2. Store the file in a location that is common to both servers - e.g. network attached storage (note this will require you to update your application logic to manage/prohibit concurrent write access to the file)
3. Write a merge routine that merges the two files together before the conversion / mailing process.

Be careful with #2. You will be tempted to create a file share on server A that allows server B to access it. In this case, you will have created a single point of failure whereby if server A fails, server B is useless because it can't get to the xml file that is on A.

Comment: Thanks for replying with all these good suggestions. Sol1 won't work as we are avoiding DB to store data and hence preferred XMl files. Sol2 looks  complicated.  For sol3, the files ar eon different servers.. so combining them into one may be cumbersome. It woul dhave been fine if they would have been on same server.

Answer (score 0):

We finally decided to use IP address for redirecting to one server all the time and hence we wil lhave one XML file which will be emailed as Excel file.